# How to type reduce method

Tags: typescript

I have following array of objects:

```js
const arrOfObject = [
  {
    name: "A",
    value: 1,
  },
  {
    name: "B",
    value: 2,
  },
  {
    name: "C",
    value: 3,
  },
];
```

I would like to reduce this array to a value:

```js
arrOfObject.reduce((prev, cur) => prev + cur.value, 0);
```

The problem is with TypeScript, which tells me:

```
TS7006: Parameter 'cur' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

How should I type this?

Comment: Is `arrOfObject` just `any[]`, then?

Comment: No problem on the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwQeQGbIEYCsCmxYC8MA2gFAwwDe5FMYcAtjgFwwBEAgmwDQ0UBucADYBXFjACMvCgF9pVPnUbi2AIR6LBo8QCZ5cmtVpKmrNgGENxrWNYBmfbwC6AblKlQkWAhwQRQwngkNExcfAA6HwATEWAcAAp4gAcffm4YYBEEAEoYAgA+GBScfhgAagys8JscdIAGbLcPcAgQIRxwoRAAc3ifPwDGoA). Types are correctly inferred.

Comment: I don't get it.

Comment: So what should I do if compiler fire with red text TS7006: Parameter X implicitly has an 'any' type. @RobbyCornelissen

Comment: Provide the necessary type information. Impossible to give more specifics without seeing the code that is causing it...

Answer (score 0):

Your TypeScript config has the --noImplicitAny setting turned on.

So you either need to specify the type **any**, explicitly.

```
arrOfObject.reduce((prev:any, cur:any) => prev + cur.value, 0);
```

or you could alternatively create a new type for your object.

```
interface NameValue {
   name: string,
   value: number
}

const arrOfObject: NameValue[] = [
  {
    name: "A",
    value: 1,
  },
  {
    name: "B",
    value: 2,
  },
  {
    name: "C",
    value: 3,
  },
];

arrOfObject.reduce((prev, cur) => prev + cur.value, 0);
```